# Correlation between study time and eyesight problems

Tags: reading, screen-time, homework, computer, eyes

Are there studies on the correlation between the time a kid spends on studying which includes reading/writing/doing homework/using computer etc and any eyesight problems they develop?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.  I'm not going to link the study because I can't find it right now, but the general consensus I've found when looking into this matter is that there can be some *temporary* strain, especially associated with computer usage (14+ hours a day) or reading in low light, but that in general it all sorts itself out after a night's sleep.  I have seen no evidence to demonstrate any long term ramifications of time spent studying on eyesight.

Comment: I hope that holds for adults as well.

Comment: That is what the studies I've seen seem to indicate.  Tag me again if you want me to try and dig it up.

Comment: Only if you have it on hand, I would not worry otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

So there is definitely a link between time spent studying and Myopia. It looks more like correlation than causation though. The real culprit seems to be - lack of daylight exposure.

See [this article in this week's Economist](https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2022/06/09/short-sightedness-was-rare-in-asia-it-is-becoming-ubiquitous).

Quoting from the article:

Excerpt 1:

> A study of Inuit in Alaska, published in 1969, found that myopia was
> virtually unknown in those middle-aged or older, but that rates were
> above 50% in older children and young adults. Such a change is much
> too fast to be purely genetic, and it had happened just as the study
> participants had begun to adopt a more settled, Westernised way of
> life. But the results went against the dogma of the day, says Dr
> Morgan, and were ignored.

Excerpt 2:

> And an intriguing study on orthodox Jewish children in Israel, in the
> 1990s, confirmed the link with long school hours. It showed that
> boys—who receive intensive religious education in addition to the
> normal curriculum—were more myopic than their sisters, who do not.

Excerpt 3:

> Instead, the dominant hypothesis now is that exposure to daylight is
> the main variable. A study of Californian children, published in 2007,
> found that time spent outdoors was strongly associated with a lower
> risk of myopia. Another paper, published the following year by Drs
> Rose and Morgan and their colleagues, followed more than 4,000
> children in Sydney for three years and came to a similar conclusion.
> The type of activity—sports, walking, picnics—did not seem to matter.
> Simply being outdoors was the crucial point. The researchers
> cross-checked the close-work hypothesis and found that being outside
> drastically reduced the risk of short-sightedness, even for children
> that did a lot of it.

Excerpt 4:

> Human trials, too, confirm the theory. One of the biggest, led by
> Pei-Chang Wu of the Chang Gung University College of Medicine, in
> Taiwan, was published in 2020. It reported results from millions of
> Taiwanese primary-school pupils who had gone through the school system
> between 2001 and 2015. In 2010 the government instituted a programme
> called “Tian-Tian Outdoor 120”, which encouraged schools to take
> pupils outside for two hours a day. After it was implemented, rates of
> myopia fell, slowly but steadily, from 49.4% in 2012 to 46.1% in
> 2015—reversing a decades-long trend of rising rates.